# Wrong mapping in hibernate annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I get this error, when trying to connect two table via manytomany:
ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] Unsuccessful: alter table PARAM_TRENDVALUE add constraint FK_TrendValue foreign key (AreaID, PcID, DeviceID, ValueID) references usrIFDBMaster.tblTrdProcessValues
08:44:43,800 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] Die 'usrIFDBMaster.tblTrdProcessValues.DeviceID'-Spalte hat nicht denselben Datentyp wie die verweisende 'PARAM_TRENDVALUE.PcID'-Spalte im 'FK_TrendValue'-Fremdschlüssel.

Principaly hibernate is trying to map the wrong columns.

Param.java:

This is the key:

```
@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name = "pcId", column = @Column(name = "PcID", nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "unitId", column = @Column(name = "UnitID", nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "paramId", column = @Column(name = "ParamID", nullable = false)) })
public ParamId getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

This is the mapping:

```
/**
 * @return the connection
 */
@ManyToMany
@ForeignKey(name = "FK_Param")
@JoinTable(
        name="PARAM_TRENDVALUE",
        inverseJoinColumns={    
                @JoinColumn(name = "PcID", referencedColumnName = "PcID"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "AreaID", referencedColumnName = "AreaID"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "DeviceID", referencedColumnName = "DeviceID"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "ValueID", referencedColumnName = "ValueID")
        }
)
public List<TrendValue> getTrendValues() {
    return trendValues; 
}
```

Trendvalue.java:

This is the key:

```
@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name = "pcId", column = @Column(name = "PcID", nullable = false)),   
        @AttributeOverride(name = "areaId", column = @Column(name = "AreaID", nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "deviceId", column = @Column(name = "DeviceID", nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "valueId", column = @Column(name = "ValueID", nullable = false))
         })
public TrendValueId getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

This is the mapping:

```
/**
 * @return the params
 */
@ManyToMany(
        mappedBy="trendValues",
        targetEntity=Param.class
    )
@ForeignKey(name = "FK_TrendValue")
public List<Param> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

It´s the first manytomany I try to use, and it should work, I already tried without inversejoincolumns, with joincolumns, defining exactly the tables and datatypes in "joincolumns/inversejoincolumns", ...
Don't know what else could be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the way it should work, but it worked:  I added the connection table manually, both the foreign keys too, but, as shown in the picture I had too keep this exact order of the keys! Thats not the order as it is shown in the main table TrendValues, but it seems to be some random order...[image]

If somebody knows, why this order has to be this way, and how I can change hibernate annotations, so that it takes this same order, I'd be very grateful.

Also, I can now start the program, with the my annotations but the tables aren't changed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection-enhance) says:

> You can override the constraint name by use @ForeignKey. Note that
>   this annotation has to be placed on the owning side of the
>   relationship, inverseName referencing to the other side constraint.

```
@Entity
public class Woman {
    ...
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @ForeignKey(name = "TO_WOMAN_FK", inverseName = "TO_MAN_FK")
    public Set<Man> getMens() {
        return mens;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, tried it, but didnt change anything on my problem, same error. I looked up the database connections hibernate tries to do, he tries to map AreaID with AreaID => Correct, DeviceID with PcID => Not correct, ValueID with DeviceID => Not correct and PcID with ValueID => Not correct

Comment: Sexist comment: I'm glad it's a ManyToMany and not a OneToMany :-)